# PHP select using result query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi i am an intermediate at php.
I want to fetch data from a table and use that fetched data to select another item from a different table. And then put those all result values into an array.

My original php code is like below.

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "select title, nickname, date, cos_id, likecount from A where area_tag='$tag'");
$result=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result, array('title'=>$row[0], 'nickname'=>$row[1], 'date'=>$row[2], 'cos_id'=>$row[3], 'likecount'=>$row[4]));    
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

'cos_id' is a string value such as "ABC, Hello, Good".
So if i get the cos_id from the table A, i want to split that String into "ABC", "Hello", "Good". Then use each String such as:

```
select name from B where tag='ABC',
select name from B where tag='Hello',
select name from B where tag='Good'
```

Eventually,
i also want these three result values to put into array like

```
array_push($result, array('title'=>$row[0], 'nickname'=>$row[1], 'date'=>$row[2], 'cos_id'=>$row[3], 'likecount'=>$row[4], 'ABCResult'=>$row[5], 'HelloResult'=>$row[6], 'GoodResult'=>$row[7]));
```

Is this possible? 
I found some information of splitting String, however i have no idea how to select and put the new result values into the original result array.

Since the cos_id data is something like ABC,Hello,Good...
    select contentid, hit from B where tag IN (cos_id)

then i get some values like this.
    contentid hit
     1111      1
     2222      2
     3333      3

I want to put these results into this array...
         array_push($result, array('title'=>$row[0], 'nickname'=>$row[1], 'date'=>$row[2], 'cos_id'=>$row[3], 'likecount'=>$row[4]));

Comment: You can use where IN clause in sql to select data.

Comment: What is the schema of your table B?

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya For example, i want to fetch name, hit, image from table B where tag is 'ABC'. Do i have to use Loop statements?

Comment: @TheDongster No you can do it by single query using IN statement in MySql. Check below answer.

Comment: @TheDongster I am not able to write comment, You can ask here what you want. :)

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya  if i got three result value set, then how should i merge these three result value set into that result array? any ideas?

Comment: @TheDongster Can you please create separate question for that? And please paste your results of Table A and Table B over there. Because i can not paste code here in proper format and yes not without your data.

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya can't you edit your answer??

Comment: @TheDongster Yes but for that i want your results from table A and table B

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136589/discussion-between-maulik-savaliya-and-the-dongster).

Comment: @TheDongster, Now i understood you need to do it on PHP level not on MySql level. :)

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya okay actually thanks for your sql information. I wanted php level solving, too...

Comment: @TheDongster, Sorry i can not help you for PHP Level. :(, May be creating new issue will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of below:

```
select name from B where tag='ABC',
select name from B where tag='Hello',
select name from B where tag='Good'
```

You can execute query like below:

```
select name from B where tag IN ("ABC, HELLO, GOOD");
```

Comment: Wow i should try with this. By finding some info of IN statement, i can actually have a try~! thanks

Comment: Can i ask one more? if i got three result value set, then how should i merge these three result value set into that result array? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test with an array of values

```
$arr=["ABC, Hello, Good","DFG, Sup, Bad"];
$temp = implode(',',$arr);

$exp=explode(',',$temp);
   $sql = "SELECT name from B Where tag IN ('" . implode("','", $exp) . "') ";

       echo $sql;
```

SELECT name from B where tag IN ('ABC','Hello','Good','DFG',' Sup',' Bad')

Substitute `$row[3`] for `$arr`